# srcset with a v-for

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, v-for, srcset

I might miss some basic vue.js knowledge, but I have the following question related to `<picture>` and specifically srcset

I have different formats of the same image coming from my api, like this:

```
"posts": [
  {
    "image": {
      "formats": {
        "thumbnail": {
          "hash": "thumbnail_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 245,
          "height": 138,
          "size": 76.89,
          "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_image.png"
        },
        "large": {
          "hash": "large_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 1000,
          "height": 563,
          "size": 916.23,
          "url": "/uploads/large_image.png"
        },
        "medium": {
          "hash": "medium_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 750,
          "height": 422,
          "size": 562.28,
          "url": "/uploads/medium_image.png"
        },
        "small": {
          "hash": "small_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 500,
          "height": 281,
          "size": 275.16,
          "url": "/uploads/small_image.png"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

The final results I want to obtain is something like:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://apiurl.com/large_image.png 1000w, https://apiurl.com/medium_image.png  750w, https://apiurl.com/small_image.png 500w" />
</picture>
```

I am already passing all of the formats as a prop into the component, so they are all stored as "images"

basically what I would like is to have a single **source** that can loop through the formats (not necessarily there's always large or small) and add the URL inside :srcset.

Of course I am able to do

```
<source v-for="format in images" :srcset="apiUrl + format.url">
```

which works but generates multiple **source**

What's the best approach or solution for this situation?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Solution:**

If you don't want to use *computed* or a *component*, you could just use a method where you pass a post and it returns the srcset urls.

```
methods: {
    postSrcSetUrls(post) {
        if (!post || !post.image || !post.image.formats)
            return null;

        let sizes = Object.keys(post.image.formats);
        return sizes.map(size => `${post.image.formats[size].url} ${post.image.formats[size].width}w`).join(", ");
    }
}
```

Then, in your template

```
<picture v-for="post in posts">
    <source :srcset="postSrcSetUrls(post)" />
</picture>
```

**Computed / Component Solution:**

I would make a component and use a `computed` property for what you're trying to do. You can then use `Object.keys` to get the names of the format sizes, which can then be used to loop through your formats.

I've included a snippet below, which you'll probably want to change a little, for example to include your api url.

This uses the [Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html), [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), [Template Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html), [List Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) and [Component Registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html) sections of the documentation, that might be useful.

```js
Vue.component("post-image-formats", {
  template: "<div><strong>Src Set Url</strong><br /> {{srcsetUrl}}</div>",
  props: ["formats"],
  computed: {
    srcsetUrl() {
      if (!this.formats)
        return null;

      let sizes = Object.keys(this.formats);
      return sizes.map(size => `${this.formats[size].url} ${this.formats[size].width}w`).join(", ");
    }
  }
});

let posts = [{
    "image": {
      "formats": {
        "thumbnail": {
          "hash": "thumbnail_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 245,
          "height": 138,
          "size": 76.89,
          "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_image.png"
        },
        "large": {
          "hash": "large_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 1000,
          "height": 563,
          "size": 916.23,
          "url": "/uploads/large_image.png"
        },
        "medium": {
          "hash": "medium_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 750,
          "height": 422,
          "size": 562.28,
          "url": "/uploads/medium_image.png"
        },
        "small": {
          "hash": "small_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 500,
          "height": 281,
          "size": 275.16,
          "url": "/uploads/small_image.png"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "image": {
      "formats": {
        "thumbnail": {
          "hash": "thumbnail_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 245,
          "height": 138,
          "size": 76.89,
          "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_image.png"
        },
        "large": {
          "hash": "large_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 1000,
          "height": 563,
          "size": 916.23,
          "url": "/uploads/large_image.png"
        },
        "medium": {
          "hash": "medium_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 750,
          "height": 422,
          "size": 562.28,
          "url": "/uploads/medium_image.png"
        },
        "small": {
          "hash": "small_image",
          "ext": ".png",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "width": 500,
          "height": 281,
          "size": 275.16,
          "url": "/uploads/small_image.png"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      posts: posts
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <post-image-formats v-for="post in posts" :formats="post.image.formats"></post-image-formats>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's an array of items (`posts`), each containing `formats`, so the OP would have to compute a new `posts` array.